# openapi-generator codegen: Ajv cannot resolve reference to requestBodies from openapi 3.0.0

Tags: node.js, express, openapi, openapi-generator, ajv

I created a server stub using my own openapi-3.0.0 template from [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).
While implementing the API logic for creating resource, I'm referencing a component declared under requestBodies as follows

```
components:
  requestBodies:
    SamyojyaUser:
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
           $ref: '#/components/schemas/SamyojyaUser'
        application/xml:
          schema:
           $ref: '#/components/schemas/SamyojyaUser'
    description: Samyojya User object that needs to be added to the system
    required: true
```

The API is declared as follows

```
paths:
  /samyojya-user:
    post:
      operationId: addSamyojyaUser
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/SamyojyaUser'
              x-content-type: application/json
```

However, while processing the request [Ajv](https://ajv.js.org/) complains saying

```
can't resolve reference #/components/requestBodies/SamyojyaUser from id #
```

Looking like there seems to be some issue with registering requestBodies component. I see the other components showing up in the Ajv when I debug. I am tempted to use the user component directly at the path object but I want to customize the request body further. Any thoughts on tweaking it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References to `#/components/requestBodies/...` can only be used directly under `requestBody` and not under `schema`:

```yaml
paths:
  /samyojya-user:
    post:
      operationId: addSamyojyaUser
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/SamyojyaUser'
```

Also, the indentation in the request body component in wrong - the `description` and `required: true` must be on the same level as `content`.

```yaml
components:
  requestBodies:
    SamyojyaUser:
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
           $ref: '#/components/schemas/SamyojyaUser'
        application/xml:
          schema:
           $ref: '#/components/schemas/SamyojyaUser'

      # vvvv  Note the indentation level
      description: Samyojya User object that needs to be added to the system
      required: true
```

Use https://editor.swagger.io (or other validators) to validate your OpenAPI definitions before generating code.

Comment: Indentation is a typo while formatting. Schema element is indeed the issue.